# Simplest way to get current item index within jQuery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am passing an array of objects to jQuery template (official `jquery-tmpl` plugin):

```
$("#itemTmpl").tmpl(items).appendTo("body");

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="item">Name: ${name}, Index: ${???}</div>
</script>
```

What is the easiest way to display item index in the template? Preferably without using separated external functions, without changing passed object structure, and without changing template structure (converting to `{{each}}`). Is there any built-in variable perhaps that stores current array index?

**UPDATE**
I created [a ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7137) proposing to expose array index to template item but it was closed as invalid...

Answer (score 28):

Well, it's not a **true** separate external function, but you can slap a function onto the `options` object you can pass to `tmpl`.  I've done the following and it works fine:

```
$("#templateToRender").tmpl(jsonData,
  {
    dataArrayIndex: function (item) {
      return $.inArray(item, jsonData);
    }
  });
```

In the template, you can access the function from the `$item` object:

```
<script id="templateToRender" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <li>
    Info # ${$item.dataArrayIndex($item.data)}
  </li>
</script>
```

Alternatively, instead of passing `$item.data` into the function, the context of the function is the `tmplItem` object of the template (same as $item.data).  So you could write `dataArrayIndex` as parameterless and access the data via `this.data`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cheezy hack:

```
${ _index === undefined && _index = 0, '' }
<strong>Item ${ index }:</strong> ${ content }
${ _index++, '' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this issue myself. very frustrating! 
The index of the template item for example was always available in jTemplates.
Shouldnt have been difficult to add that in i would think...

Weird thing is that in Firebug I can see the key property for each $item:
[image: item key]

But when trying to access it from a function i call from within the template:

```
<img class="profImage" src="${getProfileImage($item)}" />
```

In the function if I check the item key property either like 'item.key' or '$(item).key' I get 'undefined' and not the actual value...

Comment: key is set after template rendering completes. you can see "real" item content in the template with:

${console.log(JSON.stringify($item))}

Answer (score 2):

Create a function in javascript to increment a counter.  Then create a function in javascript to get the current position of the counter.  These functions can be called by using `{{ functionName() }}`.  In the past I have had use the function in an html element, for example, in a hidden input tag. This will enable you to use an index.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/clarkbox/jquery-tmpl/commit/993e6fa128c5991723316032abe12ff0cbbb9805

Patch you jquery.template and then you can do like this:

```
<script id=”tabTemplate” type=”text/x-jquery-tmpl”>
    <div id=“tab-${$index + 1}”>
        <!— render tab contents here… —>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do this using jQuery 1.6.4 or newer at least.

First as you'd expect iterate through a collection

```
{{each myListofStuff}}
Index: ${$this.index}
{{/each}}
```

Will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easily accessible index.  There is a key that is appended to each item.

```
<div class="item" jQuery1287500528620="1">
```

This key is accessible through jquery.  So you can do something like

```
$(".item").each(function () {
                var theTemplate = $(this).tmplItem();
                $(this).append("Index: " + theTemplate.key);
            });
```

But that's not what you wanted.  I don't think what you wanted is possible.  The ${$item} object is supposed to represent the tmplItem() method, but it doesn't provide a value for `${$item.key}.`  Using `${$.tmplItem().key}` produces 0 for each row.

So the answer to your question is..... No.

Answer (score 0):

simply define one global variable for counting:

```
var n = 0;
function outputTemplate(){
    return $( "#template_item" ).tmpl(datas,
          {
              getEvenOrOdd: function(){
                  return ++n % 2 == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even';
              }
          } 
    );
}
```