# Set a class or not depending of the item index

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I'm rendering a table with jquery-tmpl, and I don't get how to do a pyjama. Basically what I want is set the class "shadowed" to the items with a `index%2==0`.

I'm trying [with this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895329/simplest-way-to-get-current-item-index-within-jquery-template), but apparently I have a little mess with the jquery-tmpl syntax:

```
<script id="theCommentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr {{if ${$item.dataArrayIndex($item.data)} %2==0 }} 
                          class="shadowed" 
                    {{/if}}><td>${Reviewer}</td><td>${Date}</td><td>${StatusFrom}</td><td>${StatusTo}</td><td>${Comments}</td></tr>
</script>
```

And this is the call:

```
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetPhotoAudit","Photos")/' + id, function (jsonData) {

        $('#theCommentTemplate').tmpl(jsonData,
        {
            dataArrayIndex: function (item) {
                return $.inArray(item, jsonData);
            }
        }
        ).appendTo("#audit tbody");
    });
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to do this within the template code?

Can you not just use the `:odd` or `:even` psuedoclass selectors to add the class.

For example:

```
$("#mytable>tbody>tr:even").addClass("shadowed");
```

Comment: Yes, I knew this way, but I want to do it with tmpl because I want to know how to do it. Thanks anyway!