# Building a form from json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, model-binding

I'm fetching an array of viewmodels from my controller using jquery+json. I then build a form where each row in a table represents one viewmodel.

My question is: How should I name each form element so that I can get it to my controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult Update(MyViewModel[] models)
{
}
```

Edit: I'm using jquery-tmpl to generate the form, and I'm also trying to figure out how to get an index variable in it (if that's needed for the form generation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

My jquery template:

```
<script id="wagonTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="wagoncheck" name="wagons[${$item.getIndex()}].IsSelected" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="wagons[${$item.getIndex()}].WagonId" value="${WagonId}" style="width:120px" />
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="wagons[${$item.getIndex()}].WagonNumber" value="${WagonNumber}" style="width:20px" />
        </td> 
</script>
```

Method that loads the template:

```
function loadWagons(trainId, partId) {
    $.getJSON('/train/wagons/' + escape(trainId) + '?partNo=' + partId, function (data) {
        $wagons = $('#wagons tbody');
        $wagons.empty();

        // the function used in the template to get an index.
        var tmplOptions = {
            getIndex: function getIndex() {
                return $.inArray(this.data, data);
            }
        };
        $("#wagonTemplate").tmpl(data, tmplOptions).appendTo($wagons);
    });
}
```

In other words:

To get a `YourModel[] items` argument in your controller action you need to name the items as `items[0].MyProperty' where`0` should correspond to the index in the array.

To get an index in a jquery template, just use pass a method in the options to the template function. I'm using a slightly modified version of the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895329/simplest-way-to-get-current-item-index-within-jquery-template). Passing the item as done in that answer is not necessary as `this` points on the current item.