# how to reapply knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, zebra-striping

Currently I have a knockout binding that stripes rows in a list which works fine

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stripe = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //creates the dependency
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var even = allBindings.evenClass;
        var odd = allBindings.oddClass;

        //update odd rows
        $(element).children(":nth-child(odd)").addClass(odd).removeClass(even);
        //update even rows
        $(element).children(":nth-child(even)").addClass(even).removeClass(odd); ;
    }
}
```

Triggered from

```
<button data-bind="click: addWidget" style="display:none">Add Item</button>
```

The problem I have is when reloading data from the server , I call addWidget() manually in the view model the stripe binding handler is not applied - all rows appear as same color, if I click the html button then the binding happens and stripes appear

```
var ViewModel = function() {

     self.addWidget();

});
```

Is it possible to reapply this custom binding manually in js?

Thanks

Edit:

The stripe binding gets applied like so

```
<div data-bind="foreach: widgets, stripe: widgets, evenClass: 'light', oddClass: 'dark'">
```

Comment: I don't see where you're using the `stripe` binding.

Comment: Updated comments. The striping works only if I add items with the html button, I'd like to reload data from the server, manually add those items to the view model and have this custom binding reapply.

Comment: 2 times semicolon, end of the line in your first code block: .removeClass(odd); ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just use CSS for this? Something like:

```
div.widget:nth-child(2n) { background: grey; }
```

Then each row would update regardless of how it got added.

Answer (score 1):

Zebra effect - a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440155/1155804) and a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HJ8zJ/) example.

or just use the index var in your foreach loop for your list or table tag element ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linuxbender/NnTGF/)):

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myList">
    <li data-bind="css: { 'even': ($index() % 2 == 0) }">
        The value is <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a striped effect, you do not need Knockout, use CSS like Tom Hall suggest. However if you insist, here's my take on your problem (assuming you are using ko 2.1.x+):

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <tr data-bind="css: {odd: $index()%2} ">
            <td>Test Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
var VM = {
    rows: [{},{},{},{},{}]
};

ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

All you need to do is provide a CSS class `.odd`. In case you also want to style the even rows, you can either put a default background-color on `<tr>` or provide a `.even` class, that's applied to the element with the negated 'odd' condition.

Here's a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xQab/1/)