# Conditionals in jQuery templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have a jquery template setup like this:

```
<script id='tmpl-video_list' type='text/x-jquery-tmpl'>
<li>
    <a href='${url}'><br/>
        <span class='image_border'>
            <span class='image_container'>
                <img src='${thumb}' alt='' title='' />
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <div class='search_block'>
        <span class='name'>${caster_name}</span>
            <a href='${url}'>
                <span class='search_title'>${title}</span>
            </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

And the data I'm sending looks something like this:

```
{
    _index:i,
    url: url,
    thumb: thumb,
    name: name,
    title: title
}
```

All That is working great. My question is that if there is a way to put a conditional in there. I know about the {{if}} and such as stated in the docs but I'm wondering if you can do something like this:

```
{{if ${_index}+1 % 5 == 0}} class='last_search_video' {{/if}}
```

I tried that and it didn't work. I actually don't like the `_index` in my object but I thought I'd give that a change. I'm thinking the current index is passed into the loop for the template but I have no idea.

I'm not married to jQuery's templating plugin so if someone knows a better plugin please feel free to suggest another one.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I actually don't like the _index in my
>   object

Good news! You don't actually need it. Adapting [this excellent question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3895329/497356) to your problem, you need to do a few things to make finding the index of the current item you're rendering easier:

1. Add a function in the `options` parameter to `.tmpl()` that you can use to retrieve the index of the current item:

   ```
   $("#tmpl-video_list").tmpl(data, {
       getIndex: function(item) {
           return $.inArray(item, data);
       } 
   });
   ```
2. Modify your template to make use of that function:

   ```
   <script id='tmpl-video_list' type='text/x-jquery-tmpl'>
       <li {{if $item.getIndex($item.data) + 1 % 5 === 0 }} class='last_search_video' {{/if}}>
           <!-- etc., etc., -->
       </li>
   </script>
   ```

Here's a simplified working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gsd6D/

Comment: Siiiick, I actually just read that in the docs which I should have done in the first place. Just what I was looking for nice and clean, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "templatize" the `_index` property in the `{{if}}`. You can just write

```
{{if (_index + 1) % 5 == 0}} class='last_search_video' {{/if}}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Why would it though because _index value will not be found.

Comment: @locrizak: well I am assuming that you are putting it into your template where _index will be defined and come from your data at run-time.

Comment: Correct but im assuming that if you want to use something from your data you need to call it with the ${} so the regex can pick it up. I did try it but no luck. do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry I see what you were saying now but like I said it still didn't work. Thanks for your input